# Why is array_search not working here?

Tags: php

I am writing a progress bar script that is dynamic for the frontend the result is not working but i am so close to finishing it. I am sure it will be an easy task for some of you. Please what is wrong here?

```
// Progress Bar configurations
$data = array(
    array('bronze_V','bronze_IV','bronze_III','bronze_II','bronze_I'),
        array('silver_V','silver_IV','silver_III','silver_II','silver_I'),
        array('gold_V','gold_IV','gold_III','gold_II','gold_I'),
        array('platinum_V','platinum_IV','platinum_III','platinum_II','platinum_I'),
        array('diamond_V','diamond_IV','diamond_III','diamond_II','diamond_I')
);
foreach ($data as $key => &$value):
    $value = implode(",", $value);
endforeach;
$dataimplode = explode(",",(implode(",", $data)));

$startKey = array_search($start_rank, $dataimplode);
$currentKey = array_search($current_rank, $dataimplode);
$endKey = array_search($finish_rank, $dataimplode);

$orderPercent = (($currentKey-$startKey)/($endKey-$startKey))*100;
echo "<pre>", var_dump($dataimplode), "</pre><br/>";
echo $startKey;
echo $currentKey;
echo $endKey;
```

Comment: Why does `$value` referenced?

Comment: @aldrin27 Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Well i got it from here but if i dont use it then my array just displays array instead of the values

Comment: @aldrin27 It is a reference to the current value in the array `$data` that is being iterated over. 

@Elevant What is `$start_rank`? It is `null` in this snippet.

Comment: @aldrin27 $start_rank, $current_rank and $finish_rank are variables that have a value from the array above

Comment: What's the result you get ?

FWIW: array_search can return false... you're not testing for that.

Comment: Well $endKey == 4 however $current_rank and $start_rank return false, they should both be 0 and 2, thats another think will starting the array at 0 work? or should i start it at 1?

Comment: You should check for false, sounds like they are not found in final `$dataimplode` array

Comment: i have dumped the $dataimplode array and they exist there

Comment: I just found out the issue for $currentRank being all in caps in the variable so that now returns as 2, however the $start_rank returns as false because i guess the start rank is 0 how can i change the array to start from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i managed to solve the issue, seemed like the only problem was relating to $current_rank being in all Caps in the DB so it wasnt able to match it. $start_rank seems to be working fine i believe even though it is supposed to return 0.